# What are the exact conditions for the /questions/ask/advice ("interstitial") page to show to a user?

Tags: support, asking-questions, help

Ex. the page on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice

What are the exact conditions for such pages to show to a user?

- On what sites?
- With what history/conditions of the user's contributions?
- How many times can it show up?

Related:

- [New users required to take a tutorial on how the site works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176849/997587) (where this feature was discussed and its implementation announced)
- (possibly) [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/997587) (where the answer currently states: "*At the moment, only Stack Overflow, Mathematics, and Meta Stack Exchange require new users to go through a tutorial before being allowed to ask.*", which I'm *guessing* refers to this? I'm really not sure. Does it?)

Comment: The implementation announcement was here: [Can (and should) more be done to encourage users to search first and ask only if they don't find an existing answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9710/241919). Related stats on SO (after AQW but before SG): [How often is the search dialog used on the interstitial page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388304/2821954)

Comment: I also asked around about this internally a while back... According to what I was told, the automatic redirect to that interstitial page stopped being a thing. That said, the site setting used to customize that page is still used to [customize the text in the "Asking a good question" modal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058/335251) that's shown to new users, even when it’s not specified in the primary site setting for it.